# make emacsclient connect to running emacs

Tags: emacsclient

In my `.emacs` I have `(server-start)`.

In my `.bashrc` I have:

```bash
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR="emacs-snapshot"
export VISUAL="emacsclient-snapshot -c"
```

When I run `emacsclient -c EXISTING-FILE` on the command line, I start a new Emacs, rather than connecting to the existing one.  What am I doing wrong, and how can I change it so that emacsclient finds the existing Emacs?

---

To confirm that there really are two processes: in a shell within the original Emacs:

```
$ ps -A | grep emacs
24646 tty2     00:00:03 emacs-snapshot
24658 ?        00:00:00 emacsql-sqlite
```

In the new one launched by emacsclient:

```
$ ps -A | grep emacs
24646 tty2     00:00:03 emacs-snapshot
24658 ?        00:00:00 emacsql-sqlite
24839 pts/0    00:00:03 emacs-snapshot
24897 ?        00:00:00 emacsql-sqlite
```

Is this `pts/0` a clue?

Comment: `emacsclient -c` creates a new frame but uses the existing emacs: there should be no new emacs process running. How do you check that it's a new emacs?

Comment: It runs my .emacs init script.

Comment: Weird. You are sure it's not the same process rerunning your init file (although I certainly cannot imagine how that would happen)? There are two emacs processess running with different pids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I get it to behave as expected with this config:

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
export VISUAL="/usr/bin/emacsclient-snapshot -c"
```